# Jenkins: get the build number of a Job triggered inside pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline which runs another bunch of jobs inside a stage:

```
node{
 stage("building_other_components") {
  build 'job1' 
  build 'job2' }}
```

How can I recover the build number or URL of these jobs? I just want to send the URL by mail ( Example: **http://localhost:8080/job/job1/25**/*last-changes/* , I will add the *last-changes* part)
Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you wait for the run to complete (defaults `true`), you can access the result from the returned value of the `build` step. The returned value is of the type of `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper` ([Javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html), [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/38ff3bdadad36e343115274ff4220ec5b030f517/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java)). You can see the help for the `build` step by using the [snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator).

Using part of your code as an example:

```groovy
final job1Result = build('job1')
echo "Job 1 number: ${job1Result.number}"
final job2Result = build('job2')
echo "Job 2 number: ${job2Result.number}"
```

This uses the [`getNumber()`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getNumber--) method to get the number of the executed run.

Comment: what if I trigger twice the same job in parallel? i.e. my downstream jobs have the same name

Answer (score 3):

In case of it is useful for someone:

```
def job1_props = build 'job1'
def j1EnvVariables = job1_props.getBuildVariables();
print "${j1EnvVariables}"
```

inside the j1EnvVariables the environment variable BUILD URL is present:  BUILD_URL:http://localhost:8080/job/job1/26/ 
and the BUILD_NUMBER:26 and another useful information 
to access:

```
def path1 =" ${j1EnvVariables1.BUILD_URL}last-changes/"
```

Comment: def job = build job: '<jobName>'
                        EnvVariable = job.getBuildVariables();
                        echo "${EnvVariable}"   gave me a null array.